How to change the server.log to write to the console in JBoss Wildfly (dcm4chee)
We are using the dcm4chee docker container (dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-psql:5.31.3) that is using a JBoss Wildfly. Now we like to have the content of the file /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log in the console. This way we do not loose the content when the POD does a restart.
I tried to overwrite the /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties, but this file is generated when the server starts. See also bootup logging
I could not find a setting in  https://github.com/dcm4che-dockerfiles/dcm4chee-arc-psql/blob/master/README.md
Here is the general documentation from JBoss:
general_docu
and here the section about the console
link
but I can not make sense out of it, as it looks for me, you configure the JBoss with a CLI and i do not see how to do it in a docker container.
Thanks for your help
T
Update after comment from ehsavoie
I checkout the file standalone.xml
When i look that the current configuration (see below) it would log all Level "info" to console + file. but it does not. The actual Logoutput is different for file and console. @ehsavoie did i miss something?

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="com.networknt.schema">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>

Update after comment from "James R. Perkins"
I am a 100% sure that the logs are not written to the console. I suspect the /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties to overwrite the config. Note that is file is generated everytime the server starts.
# Note this file has been generated and will be overwritten if a
# logging subsystem has been defined in the XML configuration.


# Additional loggers to configure (the root logger is always configured)
loggers=org.dcm4chee.arc.retrieve,org.dcm4chee.arc,org.hibernate.SQL,org.dcm4che3.net.imageio,org.dcm4che3.util.ReverseDNS,org.dcm4chee.arc.query,org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind,com.arjuna,org.dcm4chee.arc.storage,org.dcm4chee.arc.procedure,org.dcm4che3.net.Association,sun.rmi,io.jaegertracing.Configuration,org.jboss.as.config,org.jclouds,org.dcm4che3.net.Dimse,jclouds.headers,org.dcm4che3.net.Timeout

logger.level=INFO
logger.handlers=FILE

logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.retrieve.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.retrieve.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.hibernate.SQL.level=INFO
logger.org.hibernate.SQL.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.dcm4che3.net.imageio.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4che3.net.imageio.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.dcm4che3.util.ReverseDNS.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4che3.util.ReverseDNS.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.query.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.query.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind.level=INFO
logger.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind.useParentHandlers=true

logger.com.arjuna.level=WARN
logger.com.arjuna.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.storage.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.storage.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.procedure.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4chee.arc.procedure.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.dcm4che3.net.Association.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4che3.net.Association.useParentHandlers=true

logger.sun.rmi.level=WARN
logger.sun.rmi.useParentHandlers=true

logger.io.jaegertracing.Configuration.level=WARN
logger.io.jaegertracing.Configuration.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.jboss.as.config.level=DEBUG
logger.org.jboss.as.config.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.jclouds.level=INFO
logger.org.jclouds.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.dcm4che3.net.Dimse.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4che3.net.Dimse.useParentHandlers=true

logger.jclouds.headers.level=INFO
logger.jclouds.headers.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.dcm4che3.net.Timeout.level=INFO
logger.org.dcm4che3.net.Timeout.useParentHandlers=true

handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=ALL
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.FILE.properties=autoFlush,append,fileName,suffix
handler.FILE.constructorProperties=fileName,append
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.fileName=/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd

# Additional formatters to configure
formatters=COLOR-PATTERN


formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n

formatter.COLOR-PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n



You can either update your standalone.xml with the proper logging configuration in the logging subsystem and replace it in your image or you could log into your container and execute the jboss cli from there but the result wouldn't be persisted

@ehsavoie i updated my question with your propose for standalone.xml. please have a look at it.

The default configuration already writes to the console, e.g. stdout. From the configuration above it looks like the default and log messages should be getting written to the console. Are you just missing some or all log messages on the console?

@JamesR.Perkins I am 100% sure that the logs are not in the console. But i suspect the /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties to overwrite the config. I updated the question with details.

That logging.properties will be used until the logging subsystem is activated. Given the configuration though, I would have to assume that you're using a different profile or standalone.xml than the configuration for the one listed.

I found the solution. For some reason the dcm4chee-arc.xml is used as config. When i change this file, it worked.
In the docker compose file i added this line
    volumes:
  # change config to so the content of /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log is logged to the console
  - ./arc/dcm4chee-arc.xml:/docker-entrypoint.d/configuration/dcm4chee-arc.xml

